# Building HTML table by appending to PHP string

Tags: php, html

First let me start by saying this is a homework problem so the way I have to build this table is because of the requirements for the assignment. The requirements call for three php functions to build an html table. I have a table, td, and tr function. I think I am very close to figuring out hwo to get this to work. Just running into one small problem and was wondering if someone could help me out or explain why I am running into this problem. Here is my code:

```
<?php

    //need a constant to keep track of the number of rows
    define('NUM_ROWS', '3');

    //function to start building table
    function table()
    {
        $myTable = '<table border="1">' . tr($myTable) . '</table>';
        return $myTable;
    }

    //function to build table rows
    function tr( $myTable )
    {
        $myTable .= '<tr>' . td($myTable) . '</tr>';
        return $myTable;
    }

    //function to build table data
    function td($myTable)
    {
        $rowData = array("Planes", "Trains", "Automobiles");
        for($i = 0, $length = count($rowData); $i < $length; $i++)
        {
            $myTable .= '<td>' . $rowData[$i] . '</td>';
        }

        return $myTable;
    }

    echo table();

    ?>
```

The problem I am having is in the table function. If I write the function the way it is shown above it will display the table but it also gives me an undefined variable error on `$myTable` when I call the tr function. If I change that function to look like the function below it doesn't display my table at all and just shows a blank page.

```
function table()
{
    $myTable = '<table border="1">';
    tr($myTable);
    $myTable .= '</table>';
    return $myTable;
}
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong or can do differently?

Comment: Because `$myTable` _IS_ undefined when you call `tr()` in `table()`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not actually using the passed variable nicely anyways so just don't try to pass the variable (which you were passing before it existed and hence was complaining about being undefined); just do this:

```
<?php

//need a constant to keep track of the number of rows
define('NUM_ROWS', '3');

//function to start building table
function table()
{
    $myTable = '<table border="1">' . tr() . '</table>';
    return $myTable;
}

//function to build table rows
function tr()
{
    $tr = '<tr>' . td() . '</tr>';
    return $tr;
}

//function to build table data
function td()
{
    $td = '';
    $rowData = array("Planes", "Trains", "Automobiles");
    for($i = 0, $length = count($rowData); $i < $length; $i++)
    {
        $td .= '<td>' . $rowData[$i] . '</td>';
    }

    return $td;
}

echo table();

?>
```

Comment: Ok. This makes sense. I was thinking I just needed to append everything to one string but I can see why this would work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass

you aren't passing any parameter to function table

```
 function table($myTable)
    {
        $myTable = '<table border="1">' . tr($myTable) . '</table>';
        return $myTable;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
//need a constant to keep track of the number of rows
define('NUM_ROWS', '3');

//function to start building table
function table($val)
{
    $myTable="";
    $myTable = '<table border="1">' . tr($val) . '</table>';
    return $myTable;
}

//function to build table rows
function tr( $val )
{
    $myTable="";
    $myTable .= '<tr>' . td($val) . '</tr>';
    return $myTable;
}

//function to build table data
function td($val)
{
    $myTable=""; 
    for($i = 0, $length = NUM_ROWS; $i < $length; $i++)
    {
        $myTable .= '<td>' . $val[$i] . '</td>';
    }

    return $myTable;
}
$rowData = array("Planes", "Trains", "Automobiles");
echo table($rowData);
```